# Gradle "compile fileTree" refuses to work

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am working with a Java project that has a large number of local dependencies. My library folder is in the following format:

```
projectroot\lib\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar
projectroot\lib\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar
etc
```

Gradle does not the add dependencies when using fileTree. This is the code I am using:

```
compile fileTree(dir: '${projectDir}/lib', includes: ['*.jar'])
or
compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: ['*.jar'])
```

Gradle does however work as intended when using the following code:

```
compile files("${projectDir}/lib/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.jar")
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it work with this?

```
compile fileTree(dir: '${projectDir}/lib', includes: ['**/*.jar'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a fileTree is a bad way to declare dependencies since they can't participate in [dependency resolution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html). It looks like your lib directory follows the [Maven repository directory conventions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final) so I suggest that you do the following instead

```
repositories {
   maven {
       url uri("${projectDir}/lib")
   }
} 
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
   compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1' 
}
```